# Реклама не показывается в опубликованном приложении

Tags: ios, admob, appstore

Несколько дней назад мое приложение было опубликовано в app store. Еще на стадии разработки я добавил в него рекламу в виде обычного баннера. С тестовым идентификатором тестовая реклама успешно показывалась. Но с реальным идентификатором приложение показывало пустой баннер. Я прочитал что в iOS приложениях с реальными идентификаторами, Реклама не показываться до публикации в App Store. Но даже спустя несколько дней после публикации реклама не показываться. Как это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте настройки в рекламной сети (поступают ли запросы в рекламную сеть). Для этого нужно зайти в Google AdMob и на главной в разделе Эффективность сети Admob посмотреть поступают ли вообще запросы в рекламную сеть. Если количество запросов >0, то все настроено корректно. Пробовали открыть приложение с другого телефона ? Иногда реклама не показывается по причине отсутствия возможных рекламодателей для вашей площадки[![Запросы в Admob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7sdY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7sdY.png)

Comment: пробовал открывать с другого телефона не сработало. А как проверить настройки в рекламной сети?

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/595898)